# Powershell script which cant run using 32bit PS executor

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a scenario where I need to validate the power shell script which throws error when executing it with 32 bit powershell.exe, it should work only with 64 bit powershell.exe.

I tried to google around but could not find any solution.
I could write a code which can tell me which PS architecture is being used

```
$PtrSize = [IntPtr]::Size
if ($PtrSize -eq 8)
{
    echo "Ran in 64 bit architecture"
}
```

Anyway can I get a script which will fail with 32bit executor

Comment: this >>> `[System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess` <<< looks like what you want. the one you showed is for the OS, this is for the current process.

Comment: I am trying to achieve it with this for now $PtrSize = [IntPtr]::Size
if ($PtrSize -eq 4)
{
 throw "I want 64bit powershell"
}

Comment: my understanding is that the pointer size reflects the _operating system_ as a whole, not the powershell bit-ness. you must use something that gives you the bitness of the _current process_, not the OS.

Comment: As @Lee_Dailey pointed out, why doesn't `[System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess` suffice? And you could just `Write-Error -Message "This script is only meant to be executed in 64-bit PowerShell" -ErrorAction Stop` right? A 32-bit PowerShell can still be executed on a 64-bit OS, so the `[IntPtr]::Size` value may not be ensuring the version of PowerShell executing isn't 32-bit.